# Creating symbolic link between mapped network drive and file:// url

Tags: networking, hard-drive, links

I have a link on a shared website that points to a location on a Samba server as such:

`file://my.samba.server/directory/foo.txt`

On my local machine, I have the Samba server mapped to my m: drive. Furthermore, `m:/` is mapped to the specific directory on the server, since this is the directory I have permissions to.

When I try to access the above link, it can’t find the file since it doesn’t know where to look. Is there a way to create a symbolic link where my link would be `file://my.samba.server/directory` and the destination would be `m:/` or `m:/directory` (I'm not sure which one it would be)?

Comment: Try `file://my.samba.server/share/directory/foo.txt`.

Comment: So I figured it out. I can open the link if using IE; IE properly associates the link to the file in my mounted network drive. For some reason it wasn't working with Chrome..

Comment: This is what I needed for Chrome, LocalLinks extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works for you. It's odd though because I am able to access local shared file URLs in Chrome without that extension.